# Accessing pub/sub systems from web apps through WebSockets

Tags: websocket, socket.io, rabbitmq, publish-subscribe

I need instances of a web-app to receive notifications via WebSocket.

These notifications derive from events in backend systems; these events need to be handled in multiple ways, not only pushed to clients.

Thus a pub/sub system is ideal: events are published and *n* consumers handle them if they are relevant for their operations (e.g. by topic).

Given my lack of knowledge on WebSocket I'm having a hard-time understanding the overall architecture I need to put in place.

In the pub/sub world consumers subscribe to queues of messages related to "topics" of interest to them.

**Can the same be done in WebSockets?** (i.e.: when connecting to a WebSocket from the browser, can I specify a set of topics that the client is interested in?).

**If so, is it possible to directly connect to the pub/sub system or do I need a middle-layer that consumes from the pub/sub and pushes to websockets?**

I guess that the answer to the last question depends on the pub/sub used and would need some library over WebSocket.

I am familiar with RabbitMQ, but I can choose another pub/sub system as at the moment nothing is in place so I have no migration costs.

Thanks

Comment: I removed Kafka, but there's references online to using Akka HTTP to expose websockets for Kafka

Comment: A bit late to the game here, sorry! Familiar with Rabbit, but considering others?  Maybe check out Solace messaging. It supports MQTT natively (both over TCP & WebSockets) and other protocols/APIs (e.g. JMS). (p.,s. I work for Solace). But I've written tons of apps with Solace Java APIs in the backend talking to either Solace or MQTT JavaScript APIs in the browser.